# Question about electromagnetic Spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, frequency, mass-energy

I have question related to electromagnetic Spectrum.

If energy of photon is $E=m_e c^2$, to which part of the electromagnetic spectrum does it belong ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What does the mass of an electron have to do with photon frequency / energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $m_e$ means the mass of an electron, a photon with that much energy would be a [gamma ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray).  The mass of an [electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron) is about $.51 MeV/c^2$, and a photon with an energy of $.51MeV$ is called a gamma ray.

Comment: Thanks and this is what I was thinking but I was not sure about it.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no upper limit to $\gamma$-ray photon energies. We've detected photons with energies north of 1 TeV, about a million times your upper limit.

Comment: @KyleKanos I got those numbers from the chart at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum .  But I see from the "Gamma ray" article that the range isn't that narrow or even that well-defined, so I reworded the answer to avoid specifying a precise range.

Answer (score 2):

The energy of a photon is
$$
E = p\,c = \hbar\,k \,c
$$
$p$ is the momentum of the photon and $k$ is the wave number. You can have photons of any frecuency, so in any part of the electromagnetic spectrum. If the energy of the photon is
$$
E = m_e \, c^2 = \frac{h\,c}{\lambda} \implies\lambda=\frac{h}{m_e \, c} \approx 2.42 \times10^{-12} m
$$
which belongs to the gamma rays.

Comment: But I am interested only in the case when the energy of photon is equal to energy of electron. thanks

Comment: Is this what you wanted?